# TileMill OGR Plugin: Failed to read GeoJSON data

Tags: cartography, geojson, tilemill

I'm trying to load the following into a TileMill layer as the file build1.geojson

```
{ 
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[
        [752669,349453],[913955,-4919228],[4300965,-4865466],[4354727,-12499679],[-13010418,-12499679],[-13010418,-7123473]
        ]]
    },
    "style":{
        "fill":"red",
        "stroke-width":"3",
        "fill-opacity":0.6
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting the error shown in the title. I can't see anything wrong with the syntax so what is my error? Is it tilemill itself?

Answer (score 1):

First validate the geojson at [GeoJSONLint](http://geojsonlint.com/) - that will tell you definitively whether your problem is the syntax or tilemill. When I put your json into the validator it responded:

> Invalid GeoJSON
>
> A Feature must have a "properties" property.

Comment: Thank you very much, geojson lint is a helpful tool and something I was looking for!